# Jquery navigation using html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('.page').on('click',function(){
       $(this).next('.content').css('display','block');
           $('body').empty('');
           var post = $(this).next('.content').css('display','block');
           post.appendTo('body');

    });
```

How to clear all other thing except the .content so it's like u nagivated to a new page? I tried above code but my logic flawed. I'm new to jquery.

Comment: try `$('.page').html('');` instead of `$('body').html('');`

Comment: @Cattla .page is a link

Comment: `.empty('');` should be `.empty();` Also note than once you `.empty()` the body element, there's nothing more to retrieve, so yoru latter `var post =` will not get any desired element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can detach the node before clearing the page then append it back.

```
$('.page').on('click',function(){
   var content = $(this).next('.content').detach();
   $('body').html('').append(content.css('display','block'));
});
```

Comment: ah the .css() doesn't fire.

Comment: What if I want to go back?

Comment: @Musa :D "rel.the page" made my day! :)

Comment: bad UX, I think I better  do a popup

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.page').on('click',function(){
   $('body').empty();
   // you have just deleted the page, how would you find other objects in the page ?
   // $(this).next('.content').css('display','block');
   // Try to .append new elements to the body
});
```